# Where do I pay taxes? Freelancer living in Mexico, working for US company (not US citizen)

Tags: income-tax, mexico

I'm a resident alien living in Mexico (in temporary resident's status), and a citizen of Ukraine. I earn income from a US company to my bank account in Singapore. Where do I need to pay my income tax and what amount? (I suppose that in Mexico as I'm a tax resident in this country, but it seems that no attorney here knows for sure and I can't find information about the amount of the tax in my case).
I'd be very grateful if anyone could point me to the appropriate section of Mexican income tax legislation.

Comment: The answer is simple, Mexico.  You're resident there.  (I don't know what "temporary resident" means.  If you are resident in Mexico - you'd pay taxes there.  If not, you would pay taxes in Ukraine.)  The USA and Singapore are uninvolved.

Answer (score 2):

Mexico. You are a resident in Mexico and therefore pay taxes there. Your income from US companies is the same as if an online store had customers from the US. It doesn't matter where your customer is from. If you were employed (as in on salary or wage) with an American company there could be more hoops to jump through but as you've laid it out here, that shouldn't apply.

Comment: Some states require you to file and pay taxes on income earned in the state, even if you don't reside there. Presumably OP would need to do so if his company is in one of those states.

Comment: Also, US citizen non-residents have to file and pay taxes in the US (at least before the latest tax bill, it changed that for corporations but no idea if it did so for individuals as well), do you know Ukraine doesn't have the same requirement?

Comment: @Kevin, what states are those? "do you know Ukraine doesn't have the same requirement" - no. AFAIK the only countries that tax their non-resident citizens are the US, and (possibly) Eritrea, Libya, North Korea, Philippines.

Comment: @Khirange Looks like "[New York, Nebraska, Pennsylvania, Delaware, and New Jersey may require that employees are taxed based on their employer's location.](https://help.zenefits.com/Payroll/Learn_More_About_Payroll_Taxes/Learn_About_Employee_State_Taxes/02-Payroll_Taxes_and_Work_Locations_for_Remote_Employees/)"

Comment: @Kevin, it seems that it's about employees rather than contractors.